# C# WinForms FlowLayoutPanel locking child controls

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have a base form containing some elements like this:
 - pnlSearch of type `Panel`: search button
 - pnlActions of type `FlowLayoutPanel`: add, edit, delete, export.. etc buttons

nothing is locked, both panels' modifiers are `Private` & buttons' modifiers are `Protected`

`FlowLayoutPanel` is used to customize options in the child forms (e.g. removing the delete option) without leaving empty spaces since the elements will flow accordingly.

In a child form, the search button only is accessible. Buttons in `pnlActions` are locked in the designer but by checking the properties `Locked = False` and `Modifiers= Protected`

Tried setting the pnlActions' modifiers to `Protected` but it's still the same.

Any idea what's causing this behavior?
what's the difference between `Panel` and `FlowLayoutPanel` other than inner controls layout?
I'd post code samples if I've hand-coded anything but it's all generated by designer

I'm using VS 2013 on Win7 if that would matter
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a problem of the Designer. if you do your changes via code all work...
The problem won't be resolved because the platform is not mainteined by Microsoft anymore.

Comment: True! I can work via code normally but I thought I did something wrong to mess up with the desginer. so it's a designer bug? and the platform is _not_ mainteined by Microsoft anymore??

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I share a possible solution, in case someone needs it.

We will create a class that inherits `FlowLayoutPanel`, I name it `FlowLayoutPanelHeritable`. You can place it in the namespace that you consider appropriate, for this example the namespace is `WindowsFormsApp`.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    [Designer(typeof(ParentControlDesigner))]
    public class FlowLayoutPanelHeritable : FlowLayoutPanel
    {
    }
}
```

First we must set the modifiers of the `FlowLayoutPanel` that is in `FatherForm`, in `Protected`. Now we must make a modification by code in `FatherForm`, accessing `FatherForm.designer.cs`. We will replace each instance of `FlowLayoutPanel`, by `FlowLayoutPanelHeritable` (in the creation, and initialization of variables). Then we save, and recompile.

Now if you access `ChildForm`, you will see that you no longer have the modification restriction at design time.

Important: if you want to edit `FatherForm`, you will have to access `FatherForm.designer.cs` and replace all the `FlowLayoutPanelHeritable` to `FlowLayoutPanel` again; When you finish editing, perform the reverse process.